# Como passar um argumento dinâmico para um método no Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Preciso chamar um evento v-on:click com um argumento dinâmico.

Tentei da forma mais lógica:

`v-on:click="my_method({{value}})"`.

Não funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Faça simplesmente assim:

```
v-on:click="my_method(value)"
```

Você não precisa usar interpolação dentro de atributos HTML dinâmicos. No VueJS 2 qualquer tentativa de interpolação em atributos gera uma mensagem de erro.